# How to get the username & photourl from userid - Swift & Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, author, uid

I have another swift file where I have stored all the current user information from Firebase, but for some reason it's not working, it appears as if it has no data on it. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me find what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my firebase architecture...
[image]

```
class UserService {


    static var currentUserProfile:UserProfile?

    static func observeUserProfile(_ uid: String, completion: @escaping ((_ userProfile: UserProfile?)-> ()) ) {

        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(uid)")
        userRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            var userProfile:UserProfile?

            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
                let username = dict["username"] as? String,
                let photoUrl = dict["photoUrl"] as? String,
                let url = URL(string: photoUrl) {

                userProfile = UserProfile(uid: snapshot.key, username: username, photoUrl: url)

            }
            completion(userProfile)
        }
    }

}
```

Then I'm using the username & photoUrl to use it in my setValue function...

```
func sendDataToDatabaseFound(address: String, breed: String, phone: String, photoUrl: String, timestamp: String) {
        //por the time being photoUrl:String - wasn't added because I can't get the downloadURL
        //         func sendDataToDatabase(address: String, breed: String, phone: String, lostfound: String, photoUrl: String)
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let postsReference = ref.child("posts").child("found")
        let newPostId = postsReference.childByAutoId().key
        let newPostReference = postsReference.child(newPostId)
        // Still need to add the "photo": photoUrl --> newPostReference.setValue(["photoUrl": photoUrl]
        let toId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        newPostReference.setValue( ["address": address, "breed": breed, "phone": phone,"photoUrl": photoUrl, "timestamp": timestamp, "author": ["userid": toId, "username": UserService.currentUserProfile?.username, "profilePhotoUrl": UserService.currentUserProfile?.photoUrl.absoluteString]]) { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the code for `Auth.auth().currentUser`, you will see that it is of the class `FIRUser` which is just called `User` in Swift. `FIRUser` is a subclass of `FIRUserInfo`, which has numerous traits, including providerID, uid, displayName, photoURL, email, and phoneNumber.

You can access all of this data in the same way that you access the `uid` of the `currentUser`.

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    let providerID: String = user.providerID
    let uid: String = user.uid
    let displayName: String = user.displayName
    let photoURL: String = user.photoURL
    let email: String = user.email
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian! But then how can I send that information to the newPostReference to set the values? Also... I suppose the displayname is username? Does that still work if in my "user" child, I have it by the name of username?

Comment: Hi Ava, You can convert that data into a dictionary just like you have already done in `newPostReference.setValue()` and then upload it as the data part of the `.setValue()` block.